# Problem loading liquid physics from a saved file

Tags: physics

I ran into a problem: when I load a scene from a saved file, where liquid physics is present, then instead of fluid (it was ready when the file was saved), I get a domain in its form before applying physics to it. I would be grateful for any hints and help! Oh yes, when loading a scene, all physics settings are saved.

Comment: If you didn’t bake it, the cache will automatically delete when you close the file. Baking saves the cashe to disk.

Comment: ZargulTheWizard, I baked everything: data, mesh and particles. When opened, it is also baked, but does not work.